# A custom title bar and windows 11 window dock

Tags: delphi, windows-11

I have implemented a custom title bar on an app I am working on. I have created some custom events for titlebar double click and titlebar mousedown.

```
procedure TAdvCustomForm.TitleBarDblClick( Sender : TObject );
  begin
    if( WindowState <> TWindowState.wsMaximized ) then
      begin
        Winapi.Windows.ReleaseCapture();
        Perform( wm_SysCommand, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0 );
        SizeGrip.Visible := False;
      end
    else
      begin
        Winapi.Windows.ReleaseCapture();
        Perform( wm_SysCommand, SC_RESTORE, 0 );
        SizeGrip.Visible := True;
      end;
  end;

procedure TAdvCustomForm.TitleBarMouseDown( Sender : TObject; Button : TMouseButton; Shift : TShiftState; X, Y : Integer );
  const
    SC_DRAG = $F012; //stumbled on by accident

  begin
    if( Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft ) then
      begin
        self.DoubleBuffered := True;
        Winapi.Windows.ReleaseCapture();
        Perform( wm_SysCommand, SC_DRAG, 0 );
        self.DoubleBuffered := False;
      end;
  end;
```

What I am am unable to find is the Windows 11 hook to show the window dock when dragging the window. As in the image.

[image]

How do I modify my mousedown event to show it?

Comment: Using a custom title bar is one of the simplest ways to make your app more quirky and less compatible with past, present, and current versions of Windows.

Comment: I like the quirky and less compatible, and, yes I could use the styles framework of Delphi to skin the tiltle bar, but hey, in for a penny in for a pound.